# yahoo cannot deliver e-mail to my server over TLS

Tags: ssl, postfix

I am getting the following error in the logs for inbound yahoo e-mails:

```
postfix/smtpd[8679]: SSL_accept error from sonic324-12.consmr.mail.gq1.yahoo.com[98.137.70.36]: 0
postfix/smtpd[8679]: warning: TLS library problem: error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:s3_pkt.c:1278:SSL alert number 46:
postfix/smtpd[8679]: lost connection after STARTTLS from sonic324-12.consmr.mail.gq1.yahoo.com[98.137.70.36]
```

It only happens with yahoo and their client reconnects in plaintext. 
I am on Postfix 2.11.0 and OpenSSL 1.0.2h. I am using a Let's Encrypt certificate.

Comment: You really should disable SSLv3 completely.

Comment: It already is: smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3

Comment: Don't you mean smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols.....

Comment: Both smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols and smtpd_tls_protocols are set to !SSLv2, !SSLv3. In this context, we are talking about port 25 and STARTTLS, so smtpd_tls_protocols is relevant.

Comment: @Mart I am on postfix version 3.1.0 and have the same problem. As you mentioned, it's just Yahoo, I see google and many other clients are able to do STARTTLS just fine with my server. Only yahoo fails, and then turns around to connect in 'plain'.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, this is absolutely a Yahoo SMTP issue. They fail to implement opportunistic TLS correctly, and shoot themselves in the foot by sending in the clear (without TLS) when WebPKI authentication fails. That makes no sense, sending in the clear is never more secure, and still not authenticated. Yahoo engineers have on a few occasions promised to fix this, but it has not (August 2018) happened as yet.

Answer (score 0):

A root CA chain required to be defined in postfix as SMTP server? I think not true.
The whole point of having CAs, is that I can check your server|client cert. with a 3rd party CA or with myself if I have the CA cert. that your server|client cert. is derived from. Yahoo - as SMTP client - has no insights into whatever my postfix has listed as root CA or CA chain. Even if it does gain such insights, what would it learn - that I made my own CA cert. and from that my own server cert.?

Tested by adding my root CA cert. to the miriad of other CA certificates in /etc/ssl/certs, hashing that, and having
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
in main.cf

Yahoo delivering mail (as client) still fails on STARTTLS, and reverts to clear text mail delivery. Shoot in the foot continues.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a Yahoo SMTP issue. Rather, you need to have a valid certificate and CA chain defined in your Postfix `main.cf` file.

```
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/root.crt
```

Add your root CA chain to this file and restart Postfix.

Comment: Or with a letsencrypt cert (like the OP says he is using) just use the `fullchain.pem` file